# Laravel - use AJAX with routes outside .blade file

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using AJAX in my website for some simple tasks and I'm using Laravel `{{ route(...) }}` in the AJAX `url` parameter to call my PHP functions. At first it didn't work because I didn't have it inside a `.blade` file, but now that I have it, it's inside of a `<script>` tag and it just seems really clunky because I have like 5 AJAX functions and they are all just stacking with the HTML and it's annoying me... In terms of functionality, it works amazing, but I was wondering if there was any way of putting it in a JS file and calling it somehow.

Summing it up, I call Laravel routes in AJAX and I wanted to use them outside `.blade` files.

Thanks alot for your time!

Comment: Yeah, `{{ route() }}` will only be available in `.blade.php` files, as `{{ }}` is `.blade` syntax, and `route()` is a Laravel function. All that `route()` method does is generate a `/url/to/whatever`, so if you know the Routes, and they aren't going to change, you don't have to use `{{ route(...) }}` in your JS, you can just do `$.post('/url/to/whatever', { ... })` (as an example with jQuery, same idea for base JS)

Comment: Another way I've seen done is something like: `let userPath = "{{ route('users.show', ['user' => ':user_id']) }}";`, then, when you want to do an AJAX request to that URL, you'd do `$.post(userPath.replace(':user_id', user.id), { ... });`. This lets you use JS variables, since `{{ route('users.show', ['user' => user.id]) }}` would blow up, as `user.id` is a JS variable, and cannot be used inside of `route()` 

Comment: You can define any JS variable first in blade file, then call any of those defined variables in JS files (that have to be included after definition block).